# JWT cookie is removed when browser is restarted

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, express-jwt

In my authentication, there is no jwt expire date, and it is working well until you restart the browser. Normally, it is not a big problem in desktop since we don't restart safari or chrome that often, but I am making it into a pwa to use mobile, and I have to fix jwt to be not removed when browser is restarted.

JWT works fine when refreshing the page, but not restarting the browser. I am wondering conceptually what would have went wrong in this case. I am using nodejs with express for backend and sveltekit for frontend.

Comment: How are you storing the JWTs on your frontend after authentication ?
Is it in localstorage or just runtime memory ?